# What does this instruction do in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86

So I don't know what this instruction does as I am starting just assembly.
What does this instruction do?

```
 cmp byte ptr [edi],00 add [eax],al
```

Comment: That is actually 2 separate instructions. Not sure if it was just the way you formatted it. But they should be on 2 separate lines. `cmp byte ptr [edi],00 ` is one instruction `add [eax],al` is another. The first assumes the value in the _EDI_ register is a pointer to memory. `cmp byte ptr [edi],00` then compares the byte at the memory location pointed to by _EDI_ with the value zero.

Comment: `add [eax],al` assumes that _EAX_ has a memory address in it. The value in the 8 bit register _AL_ is added to the byte pointed to by the _EAX_ register. Although that is legal, it doesn't make a lot of sense to do from a practical standpoint.

Comment: You really should find some good tutorial on _MASM_ assembler with 32-bit code (which this appears to be); or a good book; and maybe even talk to a teacher assistant if this is for school.

Comment: `add [eax], al` is also what you get when you disassemble zeroes. It could be real code, but be wary when you see it

Comment: @harold : as I said "practical uses". If I saw that within generated code I would probably investigate to ensure that it was legitimate.

Comment: Great - that's two down, [676 to go](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15922708/2564301). Probably some more by now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact,Those are two seprate instructions :

```
cmp byte ptr [edi],00 
add [eax],al
```

The first one goes to memory address pointed by `edi` register & fetches the first byte starting from that address , then comparing it to `00=0`.

---

The second instruction throws away the result of the first instruction by overwriting all the flags without depending on them.

It moves the content of `al` (8-bit register) to memory location pointed by `EAX` , but since `al` is the lowest byte of `eax`, its just like we are copying the lowest byte in the address pointed by `eax` to memory location pointed by that address (which i think is meaningless).

Before execution: Suppose `eax=0x00405060`

```
--------------------
Address    |  Content (1byte)
--------------------
0x00405060 | 00
```

After Execution: `eax=0x00405060` (doesn't change)

```
--------------------
Address    |  Content (1byte)
--------------------
0x00405060 | 60
```

If you notice after the instruction execution, we have copied the lowest byte of the address (60) to memory location pointed by that address.

Comment: The first instruction doesn't interact with `eax` at all.  You shouldn't still list your 0x00405060 example address as the address for the byte-compare.

Comment: I never did this !! @PeterCordes

Comment: Your formatting was very confusing, with giant bold text.  I missed the tiny paragraph where you said you were talking about just the 2nd instruction, rather than one table per instruction.  I re-formatted your answer to look more like what it appears you were trying to do with markdown.  (Outside of code blocks, `---` is an hrule, or a headline fontsize if used on a line right below something else.)  I also took the liberty of adding a paragraph to point out the most important observation.  Anyway, re-edit it yourself to make further improvements if you want.